# Coloring the Square. Burnside's lemma.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polya-counting-theory

Question from my last exam:

We paint the vertices of a square with five colors: A, B, C, D, and E. Two ways of painting are considered identical if one can be transformed into the other through an isometry of the square, possibly combined with swapping the colors $A \leftrightarrow B$ or $C \leftrightarrow D$. For example, the squares ${ }_{C A}^{A B}$, ${ }_{B A}^{C B}$, and ${ }_{A D}^{B A}$ are considered identical, but different from ${ }_{C A}^{B A}$. Find the number of different ways to paint the square.

Usually, when solving such problems, I had to create a table like the one below and manually count all the fixed points. Then, using Burnside's lemma, I had to calculate the average, which would be the result.

For example, for coloring the midpoints of opposite edges, we have $3+8$, because when using one color, we have $3$ options (the whole square is colored with A, C, or E), and for two colors, we have:

- $A, B = B, A$ (where the first letter represents the color of the first pair of vertices, and the second letter represents the color of the second pair of vertices)
- $C, D = D, C$
- $A, C = B, C = A, D = B, D$
- $C, A = C, B = D, A = D, B$
- $A, E = B, E$
- $E, A = E, B$
- $C, E = D, E$
- $E, C = E, D$

And the table looks like this:

| Rotation | Number of Fixed Points |
| --- | --- |
| Identity |  |
| $180^{\circ}$ (2x) (midpoints of opposite edges) | $3+8$ |
| $180^{\circ}$ (2x) (opposite vertices) |  |
| $90^{\circ}$ (center of the square) |  |
| $180^{\circ}$ (center of the square) |  |
| $270^{\circ}$ (center of the square) |  |

Apparently, this time, it is not the expected method to solve the problem, and it's not surprising because it would take quite a lot of time and cases to consider. What is another way to count these colorings?

Comment: I think you should still use Burnside's lemma. How can you consider the swapping in your action? What group can you use?

Comment: I think that the Burnside Lemma is intended, but that  the group in question has order $8\times 2\times 2$.

Comment: @FreeFunctor Based on another comment maybe I can use something like $D_8 \bigoplus D_2 \bigoplus D_2$, where $D_n$ is Dihedral group. Although this would mean that swapping is considered to be some kind of rotation which doesn't seem right.

Comment: Ok, you got the right group. Swapping isn't a rotation... I don't understand your point

Comment: @FreeFunctor Actually, shouldn't it be $D_4 \bigoplus D_1 \bigoplus D_1$, as $D_4$ has 8 elements? I know swapping is not a rotation, but I don't know any other way to interpret it to simplify counting.

Comment: @Michal It's an ACTION, not a rotation or reflection or whatever. [Notation: many of us use $D_8$ to mean the dihedral group of order $8$, etc.]

Comment: @ancientmathematician Okay, but I don't think I can come up with anything.

Comment: You have my sympathy: this seems to me to be grotesquely complicated to be set as an exam question. I started to count the fixed points but have chickened out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using **Power Group Enumeration**, where we cover the
cycles of the  slot permutation group with cycles of  the group acting
on the colors. We require the cycle  indices of the two groups. We get
for  the slots  (symmetries of  the square)  that they  are:

- identity, $a_1^4$,
- horizontal /  vertical flip,  $2 a_2^2$,
- diagonal flip,  $2a_1^2 a_2$,
- rotation, $90^\circ$: $a_4$,
- rotation,  $270^\circ$: $a_4$ and last,
- a rotation by $180^\circ$: $a_2^2.$

This yields the the cycle index

$$Z(Q) = \frac{1}{8} 
(a_1^4 + 2 a_1^2 a_2 + 3 a_2^2 + 2 a_4).$$

The cycle index for the colors is by inspection

$$Z(C) = \frac{1}{4} 
(b_1^5 + 2 b_1^3 b_2 + b_1 b_2^2).$$

Examining all the pairs we get a contribution of

|  | $b_1^5$ | $2b_1^3 b_2$ | $b_1 b_2^2$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $a_1^4$ | $5^4 = 625$ | $2\times 3^4 = 162$ | $1^4 = 1$ |
| $2a_1^2a_2$ | $2\times 5^2 \times 5 = 250$ | $4\times 3^2 \times (3 + 2) = 180$ | $2\times 1^2 \times (1+2\times 2) = 10$ |
| $3a_2^2$ | $3\times 5^2 = 75$ | $6\times (3+2)^2 = 150$ | $3\times (1+2\times 2)^2 = 75$ |
| $2a_4$ | $2\times 5 = 10$ | $4\times (3+2) = 20$ | $2\times (1+2\times 2) = 10$ |

Adding everything up and averaging over $32$ we have at last

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{49}$$

colorings.  As  for  this  being   an  exam  problem,  the  amount  of
computation  required  and  the  order   of  the  values  that  appear
presumably  makes  it possible  to  do  it  in about  fifteen  minutes
supposing the author is sure of their arithmetic.

**Remark on the PGE algorithm.** The  heart of the PGE algorithm is to
compute the number of orbits by Burnside's lemma which says to average
the number  of assignments fixed by  the elements of the  power group.
But this  number is easy  to compute.   Suppose we have  a permutation
$\alpha$ from the slot permutation group $Q$ and a permutation $\beta$
from $C$.   If we place  the appropriate number of  complete, directed
and  consecutive copies  of  a  cycle from  $\beta$  on  a cycle  from
$\alpha$ then  this assignment is  fixed under the power  group action
for $(\alpha,\beta)$  , and  this is  possible iff  the length  of the
cycle from  $\beta$ divides the  length of  the cycle from  $\alpha$ .
The process yields as many assignments as the length of the cycle from
$\beta$.

For example, with the pair $a_1^2 a_2$ and $b_1^3 b_2$ we can cover an
instance of  $a_1$ with instances of  $b_1$ of which there  are three,
producing  $3^2.$ The  cycle $a_2$  can be  covered with  instances of
$b_1$ or instances of $b_2$, producing $3+2.$ (There is only one
instance of $b_2$.)