How can I apply Burnside's Lemma to this problem?
Given $6$ distinct colors, let $a_i$ represent the quantity of the $i$-th color, satisfying the equation:
$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6 = 6$
Count the distinct ways to color the six faces of a cube using these colors, where two colorings are considered identical if one can be transformed into the other through cube rotations.

so, your question is simply how many ways are there to color faces cube using 6 distinct color, because the equation says that we can also color each faces to same color. there are many solution for it in this site, just check this:[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745718/coloring-the-square-burnsides-lemma?rq=1]

This question is similar to: Coloring the Square. Burnside's lemma.. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
